How to remove an Arraylist row when it is not located in Main Activity
I have created an Arraylist of items. Once an item is selected, it goes to a new activity for the price to be calculated once the quantity is selected. Upon clicking cart, it goes to another activity where the list of items can be listed. What code may i use to remove a row? My code is as below and arrayList2.remove(pos) doesn't work and cannot remove the row.
FirstShoppinglist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id)
    {
        //arrayList2.remove(pos);
        //arrayList2.remove(Integer.valueOf("Navel oranges"));
        /*
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "long clicked at: " + actual_position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        arrayList2.remove(pos);
        */
        return true;
    }
});


Please provide an [mre]. My guess is that you do not need Android Studio-specific classes or methods to reproduce the problem, but you should provide a runnable example that we can use to quickly verify the issue.

Right now, two approaches are coming into my mind: (1) Create a global reference of that arraylist and then update that in any activity you want. (2) Store the arraylist in shared preferences or a file, then update/retrieve it any activity you want. Hope this helps

Hello Just Learning, welcome, please, use System.out.println( arrayList2.remove( pos )); and show the result.

@Vansh, I don't know what you mean. Can you share the code?

@Marce, TempHolder 6 and 8.00 is the earlier code.
//System.out.println( arrayList2.remove( pos ));
Log.i("arrayList2.remove( pos )", String.valueOf(arrayList2.remove(pos)));
return true;
TempHolder6
com.example.arraylist3               I  8.00
--------- beginning of crash
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (11213) for package com.example.arraylist3 ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (11260) for package com.example.arraylist3 ----------------------------

@JustLearning I think I'm a bit confused in reading the question. First of all, you have a list of items, say, arrayList1. Now, when an item is selected from arrayLsit1, it goes to another activity, say, Activity2. Now, when cart button is clicked in the Activity2, it goes to third activity, say Activity3. And in this Activity3, you have to display items from arrayList1, right?

@Vansh Patel, Yes that's correct. The issue is I want to program it so that when the activity3 has > 1 item, you can remove all others leaving at least 1 item. Is my code correct?
